# how to group only first 3 and the last character in JavaScript (e .g. 123456789 => 123 45678 9)

Tags: javascript, regex

How to group only first  3 and the last character in JavaScript (e .g. 123456789 => 123 45678 9)
I have tried to do :

`.toString().replace(/(\d{3})/g, "$1 ").replace(/(^\s+|\s+$)/, "");`

but it groups every 3 (I need the first 3 only)

Could anyone explain where I am wrong and how to fix that?

Much appreciated

Comment: remove `/g` would be a start

Comment: `123456789..toString().replace(/(\d{3})/,"$1 ").trim()`

Comment: What should be the result for `1234` or `123`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to remove the global `g` search from the first regex and you should be good to go.

Edit: To accommodate the last character, you could do a similar `replace`.

```js
console.log(
  123456789..toString().replace(/(\d{3})/, "$1 ").replace(/(\d{1}$)/g, " $1")
)
```